# Detect java thread starting to wait and run some code

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there any way to put any sort of event listener that will be called when some thread - for example, the current thread -  stops its activity and starts waiting or terminates?

I need this for the object to be notified and release some resources, when it is not in active use in this thread but still stored in memory somewhere that prevents it from being garbage collected - otherwise I'd place that resource releasing code  in finalise() method.

**UPD**
Use case: an object that keeps a reference to a jdbc resultset or a database connection; the respective close() or commit() should be called automatically when the object is set aside temporarily or discarded at all without requiring the program to call any sort of cleanup method. 
(There is no question how do I lock the object to be accessed from only one thread at a time, it is solved.)

Comment: Don't rely on `Object#finalize()` https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8165641. To your problem, you want something like [ListenableFuture](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html)

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 2):

The distinct non-answer: wrong design point. *Threads* don't "own" resources.

Threads are simply "threads of execution". They run the code you tell them to run. Therefore a thread doesn't own any of the objects it comes by.

As a consequence, there are no built-in mechanisms to help with your requirement. You would have to implement something yourself, relying on monitoring threads, and their states. Which would be a hard and challenging task. Mainly because: multi threading is hard.

The serious recommendation here: step back from this design. Rather think about other, different ways to deal with such "resources".

Comment: Thanks for admitting it's not an answer. The reasoning why the Thread class has getState method but doesn't have any sort of onStateChange(callback) "because threads don't own resources" are interesting but unconvincing. Anyway, information that there's no built-in function for my requirement is appreciated, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a wrong approach.
You can obviously lock the object and unlock it in a finally block like this:

```
private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public void useObject() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        //do something with your resource.
    }
    finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

This way if the thread that runs useObject terminates, it will execute the finally block, and unlock the lock that protects the resource.

But there's NO way to detect the thread is not having any activity. If the thread is preempted by the Operation System, there's no way for you to know about it. That's below the abstraction level, you as a developer, operate.

If you want to gain more understanding on how the OS works with threads, and what you can cannot do you should check out

> Java Multithreading, Concurrency & Performance Optimization

course on Udemy. 
It also talks about how to properly use the right locks to do this kind of safe synchronization, and get the best performance from your application when you have to share resources such as database connections.

I hope it helps